# Tracking memory usage in fortran

Tags: fortran, out-of-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, gfortran

I am building a library for integration in fortran.I have used dynamics arrays in that. The problem is, whenever I try to integrate with a very small stepsize, naturally system gets out of RAM soon, and gfortran gives error that out of memory.

Now, what I wish is to dynamically monitor the ram usage inside the library modules, and insert a stop command inside every suberoutine, that, whenever the ram usage, say goes to 4/5th of total RAM, the process will stop and give an error message, that use a timestep within some specified limit, which shall be obtained from the range of integration. Is there any way to monitor ram usage in a fortran program,and also getting info on total available system RAM within the program, which would be used to stop the program?

Comment: *The problem is, whenever I try to integrate with a very small stepsize, naturally system gets out of RAM soon* I wouldn't call that natural at all.  Fortran programs have been used for large integration problems since the year . and running out of RAM is a very odd thing to happen.  By all means figure out how to track memory usage (shouldn't be too difficult to keep a count of storage `allocate`d and `deallocate`d) but my own first thought would be to sort out the software design

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sorry Mark, I can only upvote your comment once

Comment: @high performance mark, I am asking that only. How to count the storage used by the allocated arrays?

Comment: The scheme I have used is  1.Divide the integration range into 1000 and 2000 grids. 2. Find the integration result using the two grids. 3  If the difference between them is less than maximum error, change 1000 to 1000×5 and 2000 to 2000×5. 4. If still does not converge to expected accuracy multiply woth 5 again. 5. Go on.

Comment: Well, if you must, you would stuff your code with calls to the intrinsic function `storage_size` and keep some kind of running total as your computation unfolds.  And you'd compare the results of your calculation with what your o/s thinks is the memory consumption of your program, the two won't be identical, the o/s is likely to think your program takes more space than your running total of memory used.